# Add the PayPal Mark to your payment methods page

Tags: php, paypal

I have integrated Paypal Express checkout in one of the website and I want to change the Pay option text into image with radio button like:

[image]

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can find all the paypal logos in here: https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/logo-center & here https://www.paypal-marketing.com/emarketing/partner/na/portal/logos.html

Comment: Hello MaK, Thanks for your response. Is possible to customize Paypal Checkout page?. I mean I need to change the text("Pay with my PayPal account" and "Pay with a debit or credit card") into paypal image(i.e I am giving the above URL)

Comment: Well, I am afraid you can't have any custom logos exclusive for your need from Paypal, you just have to choose from the set of images/icons available.

Comment: @MaK I don't think you understand what is asked.

Answer (score 0):

here are some answers for you.

Referencing Comment:

1. **Question**: Is possible to customize Paypal Checkout page?.
   **Answer**:
       Yes, you can customize/change (checkout page)the business name to a custom logo on the PayPal checkout page- that is all;
       please [look here for a walk-through](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1543&pmv=print&impressions=false&viewlocale=en_US) on how to do that
2. **Question**: I mean I need to change the text("Pay with my PayPal
       account" and "Pay with a debit or credit card") into paypal
       image(i.e I am giving the above URL)
   **Answer**: You don't necessarily have to do it that way, as there is not a wrong way, right way or required way; however PayPal does recommend a specific checkout display. If the only payment method is PayPal you could use this code that references PayPal and all major credit cards in one image.Here is what it looks like - http://prntscr.com/8wbh1t or you can try and grab it [Here](https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/logo-center)
3. **Example:**
   [image: Pay with PayPal Credit or any major credit card]